# How to update a phone number and address in a user data base

Tags: visual-c++

How can I update a phone number or address from a previous one in a user database? So I would start with a phone number and address already, but I need to implement a "Update Address" and "Update Number".  How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is for SQL? If it is, you can use the UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET phone_number=new_phone_number, address=new_address
WHERE user_id=the_user_id_of_the_person_you_want_to_change
```